# Rails 3.2.11 Asset Pipeline in development issue (don't load assets)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, asset-pipeline

I was creating a new app using ZURB Foundation.
There are three controllers. And ih one of them - everything works fine, all css and javascripts includes everytime when i run the server in development. But if i run my Projects#Controller, it gets only plain html, without loading javascripts and css. I tried everything, but still dunno what to do with it.

Here is the logs from the console:

When it works fine

```
Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-01-09 21:36:21 +0200
Processing by PagesController#info as HTML
  Rendered pages/info.html.erb within layouts/application (0.3ms)
  Rendered layouts/_head.html.erb (36.9ms)
  User Load (1.6ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 1 LIMIT 1
  Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (8.9ms)
  Rendered layouts/_flash_messages.html.erb (0.3ms)
  Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (66.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 368ms (Views: 365.2ms | ActiveRecord: 1.6ms)
```

But then if i go to another page from the other controller it loads only plain html from the page

```
Started GET "/projects/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-01-09 21:23:21 +0200
Processing by ProjectsController#index as HTML
  User Load (1.1ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 1 LIMIT 1
  Project Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "projects".* FROM "projects" WHERE "projects"."user_id" = 1 ORDER BY created_at desc
  Rendered projects/index.html.erb (30.8ms)
Completed 200 OK in 78ms (Views: 38.4ms | ActiveRecord: 2.7ms)
```

Gemfile

```
    source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.11'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3'
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails'
end

group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'

  gem 'compass-rails'
  gem 'zurb-foundation'
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'devise'
gem 'thin'
gem 'best_in_place'

group :test do
  gem 'capybara'
  gem 'shoulda-matchers'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg'
end
```

application.html.erb

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <%= render 'layouts/head' %>
  </head>
  <body>
    <%= render 'layouts/header' %>
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span8 offset2">
          <%= render 'layouts/flash_messages' %>
          <%= yield %>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class='row-fluid'>
      <%= render 'layouts/footer' %>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

And Controllers

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :html

  def info

  end
end


class ProjectsController < ActionController::Base
  # before_filter :authenticate_user!

  def index
    @projects = current_user.projects

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
    end

  end
end
```

Any help or ideas will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change `class ProjectsController < ActionController::Base` to `class ProjectsController < ApplicationController`, then it will know where to search the layout.

Comment: Wow! Thank's it works. Maybe you know where can I find information about this? cause `ActionController::Base` was generated with the scaffolding by default, I didn't even mentioned it.

Comment: `ActionController::Base` is used only in `application_controller.rb` by default. All other controllers usually inherits from the application controller. I think you can read more on http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html